# CSS animation-timing-function acting on midpoints

Tags: css, animation

I can't find any answers on google, so I'm trying here:
Is there a way for `animation-timing-function` property to work for an animation as a whole? Because now it is acting on midpoints, rather than on the whole animation. I mean, I have this animation:

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/Rainbow_Doge/pen/pqLjyY?editors=1100)

and the `animation-timing-function property` is set to ease-in. But rather than the whole animation easing in, the 0% - 50% part eases separately from 50% - 100% part, and because of it, the animation isn't smooth. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you just want that same effect with one timing function applied? If so is the clip-path technique you're using required or are you open to another way, like say using background linear gradient technique to accomplish the same effect?

Comment: I can probably do this some other way, but that may be useful for future - is there a way to animate something using keyframes with one timing function applied? If not, I'm just gonna try to do this using the technique you proposed.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry man I misunderstood your question on the first read. One timing function IS applied (example would be if you changed `ease-in` to `linear`) whereas what you're describing would be an expected result of a segmented keyframe animation unless you applied timing functions to each segment or an overall cubic bezier function to mitigate the segment steps visually like you desire.